# Row or 'Tablename' object in 'Databasename' type * FILE being used

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Before a RPG program that update a table (an specific record) this problem appear, How can I fix this for make a regular update in DB2 AS400, because the error message (in the title) delay the update to finally show the message and didn't let me complete the update.

Comment: Really a regular update.  You have to change the RPG program to do optimistic updates.  You'll probably also have to teach the RPG programmer what an optimistic update is.

Comment: Thank you @danny117 for your comment that generates so much value to my question. The RPG program obviously have a problem, but the question is more about how fix the high level issue :).

Comment: Although it doesn't exactly match, this seems to be SQL0913. (Including a message ID is far better than just text since the same text may come from different causes.) Did you try the options listed in the message? If so, what were the results?

Answer (score 0):

Find out what's locking the table and/or record...

**Work with Object Locks (WRKOBJLCK)** command

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it will be due to record lock. Try to check if any record is locked using DSPRCDLCK command.